# Pulling JSON into Google Sheet via API resulting in undefined values in cells

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

I have an issue with one of my API's I am trying to establish an API to call on a Customer Relationship Management tool called Streak, I am attempting to pull data via a HTTP Basic Auth GET which parses a JSON file through my script logic and then into my Google Sheets spreadsheet. The Google App Script after a few hours of development is working flawlessly (for my requirements) par one thing, my script is inserting the string 'undefined' into my google sheet cells whenever it cannot locate a value, a completely empty non existent field.

Image of Google Sheet Output issue can be seen below
Note: I have highlighted both the field property names and undefined values that are causing me grief
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4rXaBEqs2UzSU5fMFUxYW8zTm8/view?usp=sharing

The entire Code Snippet that is ran to extrapolate hundreds of records to my Google Sheet can be seen below. From my understanding my problem is within the statement row.push(field 1001 -> 1021), it is always attempting to push all fields to the sheet; however, not all records contain these fields as I may not have populated them within the source CRM. In response to this the script is populating "undefined" strings in the corresponding cells within my Sheet.

I am hoping to prevent this "undefined" string from being populated in the sheet, instead of this the cell should be blank, can someone please advise how I can tweak my code snippet to achieve this? Much appreciated! I have tried for nearly 2-3 hours to work around this issue but I am not experienced enough to find the answer, I have tried various IF statements and looked into defining variable types (i.e. integer, floating, char etc) none of which seem to work. I am sure a solution is simple once you know it, your assistance is greatly appreciated!

```
//Within this API we need to achieve collecting my data from Streak CRM us
//
//  Notes on Google API 
//      https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external
//
//  Notes on Streak API
//    https://www.streak.com/api/
//
//API Key YOUR_API_KEY Here

function myStreak() {

//Google Sheet Data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("StreakCRM"); 


//Streak API Call  
 var consumerKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY_HERE'
 var url = "https://www.streak.com/api/v1/boxes";  
 var headers = {
             "contentType": "application/json",
             "headers":{
"User-Agent": "MY_APP_NAME (App URL/your email address)",
               "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(consumerKey)
             },
             "validateHttpsCertificates" :false
             };

//Fetch Streak Data  
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
 var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

//Write Captured Streak Data to Google Sheet  
 var dataSet = dataAll;  
 var rows = [],
  data; 

  for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
  data = dataSet[i];
  rows.push([data.name,
               data.stageKey,
//             data.fields['1001'], empty field
               data.fields['1002'],
               data.fields['1003'],
//             data.fields['1004'], empty field
               data.fields['1005'],
               data.fields['1006'],
               data.fields['1007'],
               data.fields['1008'],
               data.fields['1009'],
               data.fields['1010'],
               data.fields['1011'],
               data.fields['1012'],
//             data.fields['1013'], empty field
               data.fields['1014'],
               data.fields['1015'],
//             data.fields['1016'], empty field
               data.fields['1017'],
               data.fields['1018'],
               data.fields['1019'],
//             data.fields['1020'], empty field
               data.fields['1021'],
               data.fields['1023']]);//your JSON entities here
}

  dataRange = sheet.getRange(3, 1, rows.length, 19); // 19 Denotes total number of entites
  dataRange.setValues(rows);

//Capture response code success or errors
var text = response.getResponseCode();
Logger.log(text);
Logger.log(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already accepted a good answer but if I could offer an alternative modified approach.

```
//Write Captured Streak Data to Google Sheet  
  var dataSet = dataAll,
      rows = [],
      data,
      dataFields = ['name', 'stageKey', '1001' … ]; //include all the JSON fields you want to transfer including any deliberate blanks you don't exist. 

for (i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
  data = dataSet[i];

  rows.push(dataFields.map(function (f) {
    return data[f] || '';
  });
}
```

The point here is to control the direct mapping of data fields once at the outset.

At the end of the loop then you'll see another alternative to the ternary if thrown in for good measure.

```
return data[f] || '';
```

Which is in the form

```
var foo = bar || 'default';
```

`||` is the OR you know from if statements. In effect this pattern says "let `foo` be `bar` unless it is `falsey` in which case use 'default'.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour, since those properties are missing entirely from a given row of data, they are undefined variables. When you write an undefined variable to a sheet, it is converted into the string "undefined".

To handle this, you should do a check on each property name to make sure it exists, and if it doesn't use a desired default value instead.

You mentioned you tried various If statements. The way to check if a value is specifically undefined is to do:

```
if(data.fields['somefieldname'] === undefined)
```

However, usually you just want to know if the value evaluates to false, in which case you can simply do:

```
if(data.fields['somefieldname'])
```

Which will evaluate as False if *data.fields['somefieldname']* is any value that evaluates to false, such as *null*, *false*, *0* or *undefined*, and true for any other value.

Finally, since if statements are a bit long for this particulay usage, I suggest using the "Conditional Operator" or "Ternary Operator" to handle this in your code:

```
   ( (data.fields['1002'])? data.fields['1002'] : '' )
```

Which can be read as "*if data.fields['1002'] is true, return data.fields['1002'], else return empty string*"

Here is some documentation on the the Conditional Operator:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

In a snippit of your code, it would look like this:

```
rows.push([data.name,
               data.stageKey,
//             data.fields['1001'], empty field
               (data.fields['1002'])?data.fields['1002']:'',
               (data.fields['1003'])?data.fields['1002']:'',
               ...
               ...
            ]);
```

You can specify any value for the "else" condition, a 0 instead of an empty string, for example.

Comment: Hi Cameron, 

Thank you very much for your clear explanation, my IF statement skills lead me to believe I would have needed a nested IF statement; however, your solution has made it clear else-wise and I was not aware of the Ternary Operator. This is a very clean solution that has made my code easily readable whilst achieving the desired result.

Thank you very much for your help, I will award you the points!